# PGP encrypted file using Bouncing Castle cannot be decrypted using PGP command line

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pgp

I've encrypted a file using [Bouncy Castle API](http://sloanseaman.com/wordpress/2012/05/13/revisited-pgp-encryptiondecryption-in-java/). I've successfully decrypted that file using the same API.

However I cannot decrypt the file using [PGP command line](http://www.pgpi.org/products/pgp/versions/freeware/win32/6.5.8/)

No error messages are shown but the decrypted file is not being generated:

```
C:\pgp-cli>pgp arquivo-cripto-cast5-bin.pgp
Pretty Good Privacy(tm) Version 6.5.8
(c) 1999 Network Associates Inc.
Uses the RSAREF(tm) Toolkit, which is copyright RSA Data Security, Inc.
Export of this software may be restricted by the U.S. government.

File is encrypted.  Secret key is required to read it.

Key for user ID: contine
2048-bit RSA key, Key ID 0x150AAE5B, created 2015/03/26
Key can sign.
```

Could it be a compatibility issue?

Comment: You're using a _horribly outdated_ version of PGP. If you do not want to buy a newer version, consider using GnuPG which is free and mostly even compatible with PGP's arguments (and probably has much broader usage than the good old PGP, which is owned by Symantec at the moment). There is a bunch of ways to introduce incompatibilities with this old PGP version.

Comment: I have installed GnuGP 1.4.19 and the decryption was successfull. However my client is using Symantec's PGP v10 and will not change for GnuGP. According to my client if I can get the decryption to work on PGP v6.5.8 it will work on Symantec's PGP as well

Comment: As the comment seems to actually answer your question, I posted it again as one and slightly extended it with some download links.

Comment: Jens although your comment is helpful it does not answer my question. I still need to know why my file encrypted using Bouncy Castle cannot be decrypted by PGP v6.5 and PGP v10

Comment: It is an answer for "Could it be a compatibility issue", which is what you actually asked. Then you will have to provide the files (or example files): some encrypted message and a private key. Output of `gpg --list-packets [file]` for both of might suffice, as it already gives lots of details on the algorithms in use.

Comment: I have installed Symantec's PGP 10.3.2 and was able to decrypt the file encrypted using Bouncy Castle. So it's most probably a compatibility issue with 6.5 as you have pointed out. I'm thus marking your answer as the correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

PGP 6.5.8 is *horribly outdated*, a lot changed in cryptography since then. There is a bunch of ways to introduce incompatibilities with this old PGP version, and it's hard to tell what exactly is the problem. Since that old version, new ciphers (both symmetric and assymetric), hashing and I think even compression algorithms have been introduced.

If you do not want to buy a newer version, consider using [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org) which is free and mostly even compatible with PGP's arguments (and probably has much broader usage than the good old PGP, which is owned by Symantec at the moment). A readily built GnuPG package for Windows is available on [GPG4Win](http://www.gpg4win.org/).